# how internally arraylist stored different data types using an array

Tags: java, arraylist, internals

how internally arraylist stores different data types using array. Since array is the internal implementation of an array list and in an array we can store only similar data type like string/int etc.

want to understand internal implementation of arraylist for handling data of multiple data types.

My question is actually: in a list we can add Integer, String, Boolean, anything, but internally it is implemented by an array. So how an array handles different types of wrapper into same array object.

Comment: arraylist stores objects, so it doesn't care about the type. Types are only there until compile time

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can create arraylist with <Object> type and then create your own implementation to handle multiple object types. Java arraylist also allows storing only single data type

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a generic type.

So it can't work with primitive type.

It work with object type and use array object for internal implementation.

```
Object elements[]= new Object[size];
```

For example custom list:

```
public class MyList{
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private Object elements[];

    public MyList() {
        elements = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList always requires object to store it in the list, It uses generics to create a list for specific type. For Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This creates a arraylist for Integer type, here Integer is a wrapper class for the primitive data type int, we can't create arraylist of primitive type, we need to use a wrapper class. If you don't use generics then:

```
ArrayList<> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

by default, it's get created for the Object class, which is super class of all the classes including the wrapper one.
Now:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(1);
```

Here, we created a arraylist of object, but adding 1 primitive integer, it's still valid because it's get converted into the Integer wrapper and Object is the superclass of Integer wrapper class. So if you write :

```
Object ab = new Object();
ab=1;
```

it's valid. so when you add 1 into the arraylist, your primitive 1 get's converted into the Integer wrapper class refered by Object class.

I hope this simplifies you.

In Addition with your comment, In the ArrayList class source code, you can see the array which stores all the element is nothing but:

```
 /**
     * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
     * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
     * empty ArrayList with elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
     * will be expanded to DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
     */
    transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access
```

It's a Object class's array. So it can store any object and since, the ArrayList class implement the generics, it's easy to convert this object to the specific type, if the ArrayList is created with specific one.

Comment: My question is actually: in a list we can add Integer, String, Boolean, anything, but internally it is implemented by an array. So how an array handles different types of wrapper into same array object.

Comment: Hi @anurag1007, I edited my answer for the same.

Comment: thanks Sandeep.. this answers my question

Comment: @anurag1007 Please accept the answer then and give me upvote.